# Font problem in windows xp

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, windows-xp

I set up my app in Windows XP but it doesn't recognizes the font family of my app as it was made in win server2008. I installed on XP the .NET and all. Aren't all the font familys inside NET or what to install ?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem.  Are you referring to the `font-family` in browsers, or is it something else?  Without more detail, any answer is just going to be a wild guess.

Comment: Which font was it? Server 2008 may have fonts that XP does not.

Comment: I had problems with blackadder fonts and upc fonts..., basically everything that is little more fancy and not plain normal

Comment: XP is a very plain operating system.  Buy the fonts you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Windows Server 2008 may have fonts that are not on Windows XP, such as Segoe UI. The .NET Framework itself does not install any fonts. You can't just install the font, either - you would have to license it from whoever made the font.

However, WPF also includes the ability to [embed fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx) so you don't have to install the font on the user's machine. However, you may still have to get embedding rights.

Comment: If the font isn't already on the box, yes. You need to pay someone to put it there.

Comment: Here is a MS-provided set of fonts you can use if you need to be sure you're in the clear: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746705.aspx